# Symfony, validate a field added dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

So, i create a form with FormBuilder :

```
$builder
        ->add('test', 'text')
    ;
```

On my template, i replace this field `test` with an autocomplete field (jquery token).

```
$("test").tokenInput();
```

My problem, my field `test` is require, and after the autocomplete replacement, this field is

```
display:none
```

How can i tell to symfony to validate this new field, and not the old one ?

Comment: Why do you replace the field, instead of calling `$("#{{ my_form.children['test'].vars['id'] }}").tokenInput();` ?

Comment: What is this line of code ? Oo

Comment: It's the same thing with this line

Comment: What happens, or what is the exact problem?

Comment: The exact problem, my plugin jquery token replace an input text by an input with autocomplete. so, symfony try to validate the old input text (display:none) and not the new with autocomplete

Comment: With *"validate"* do you mean that the input field is marked as "required" in the frontend? Or do you mean that one of the validator constraints is blocking the field?